# Fixing the top TR in a css Display:table

Tags: html, css

i was wondering if it is possible at all to fix the top TR in a CSS display:table class or at least make it sticky?
the first TR needs to be fixed with the rest of the tr scrolling within a set height (mainly for responsive type layouts)

```
<style>
#table {
    display: table;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;
    padding: 5px;
}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<div id="table">
<div class="tr mobile">
<div class="td"></div>
<div class="td">Homework Submitted</div>
<div class="td">Behaviour</div>
<div class="td">Assessment</div>
</div>
<div class="tr mobile">
<div class="td">table info 1</div>
<div class="td">table info 2</div>
<div class="td">table info 3</div>
<div class="td">table info 4</div>
</div>
<div class="tr mobile">
<div class="td">table info 1</div>
<div class="td">table info 2</div>
<div class="td">table info 3</div>
<div class="td">table info 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of interest, as your data appears to  be genuinely tabular, is there a reason you are not using an HTML table?

Comment: CSS-Tricks shows how to do it with tables — which is probably what you should be using here. https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/

Comment: not using <table> due to the fact that it has to be very responsive for mobile use. and switching from display:table to display: flex sorts out a lot of display issues....